# how to increase "touch-active of thumb" area of custom UISlider?

Tags: ios, uislider

My custom slider looks nice, everything is okay but its really bigger then standart one, it more like "slide to unlock". But it's difficult to start dragging ( too small active area ).

Comment: Let me try to answer with the same amount of vagueness...you are doing something wrong....

Comment: In other words, be more detailed about how you are creating it

Comment: You better make a invisible Slider Button above you custom Slider button

Comment: this could definitely Help you .,
CGRect sliderFrame = self.mySlider.frame;
sliderFrame.size.height = 42.0;
[self.mySlider setFrame:sliderFrame];